# What ever happened to the Asteroid Redirect Mission?

Tags: nasa, history, asteroid-redirect-mission, lunar-gateway

In Robert Zubrin's [Moon Direct; A purpose-driven plan to open the lunar frontier](https://www.thenewatlantis.com/publications/moon-direct) (found in the Pod Bay) there is a paragraph that says:

> Essentially, **the gateway is a vestigial form of the Obama administration’s defunct and discredited Asteroid Redirect Mission (ARM)**. As NASA describes it, ARM’s aim was “to develop a robotic spacecraft to visit a large near-Earth asteroid, collect a multi-ton boulder from its surface and redirect the boulder into orbit around the moon, where astronauts would have explored it and returned to Earth with samples.” The Lunar Orbital Platform-Gateway is the ARM except with a space station instead of an asteroid, all to come up with something for astronauts to do in lunar orbit.

While initiatives by one political administration are made "defunct" by a subsequent administration all the time, it's the "discredited" part I'm asking about here.

I don't really know what ever happened with this mission. It was a thing for a while, then it wasn't. So I'd just like to ask

**Question:** What ever happened to the Asteroid Redirect Mission?

Comment: I think you're reading too much in to it, uhoh. "Who" anyway would have "discredited" it?  It was far from a major news media story.  "Objectively" ("factually?" you mean?) it seems that the project had almost no support in Congress at any time, so, you could read that as "discredited".

Comment: The ARM is a sad story from the beginning, NASA desperate to have something, anything, to do, and then the collapse of its goals as reality set in.

Comment: Zubrin has his opinions

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Warning: There is no way to decouple politics from this; I have tried to be objective.*

What ended as the ARM (Asteroid Redirect Mission) officially began in a [speech](https://spacenews.com/obama-pledges-2025-mission-asteroid/) by then-President Obama in April 2010 at Kennedy Space Center.  This was the speech in which President Obama discussed the cancellation of the Constellation lunar landing program:

> "But I just have to say pretty bluntly here. We’ve been there
>   before."

The Obama administration's February 2010 budget request had already proposed the project cancellation, so this was not an announcement of that. In fact, that budget had proposed [cancelling the Orion spacecraft](https://www.space.com/8222-obama-aims-send-astronauts-asteroid-mars.html) as well.  However, in this speech President Obama made an announcement about a crewed mission to an asteroid by 2025 which would use Orion.  Please note the exact wording - that is important.

> “And by 2025 we expect new spacecraft designed for long journeys to
>   allow us to begin the first ever crewed missions beyond the Moon into
>   deep space. So we’ll start **by sending astronauts to an asteroid** for
>   the first time in history.”

(emphasis mine)

Note: this type of mission had been studied before as part of Constellation planning as this November 2006 [article](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/15750600/ns/technology_and_science-space/t/nasa-studies-sending-crew-asteroid/) and this November 2009 [article](https://www.space.com/7583-plan-human-mission-asteroid-gains-speed.html) describe, so it was not completely novel.

In [June 2011](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/43866501/ns/technology_and_science-space/t/daunting-space-task-send-astronauts-asteroid/) NASA was still trying to plan the mission. The thought was to send a crew to a near-Earth asteroid but no destination had been chosen.

[image]

In [2013](https://www.space.com/20591-nasa-asteroid-capture-mission-feasibility.html) and [March 2014](https://www.space.com/25235-nasa-asteroid-capture-mission-mars.html) President Obama's NASA Administrator Bolden was talking in terms of capturing a small asteroid whole and returning it to an orbit near Earth. (To meet the "sending astronauts to an asteroid" goal literally)

[image]

By [May 2015](https://www.space.com/29323-nasa-manned-mars-exploration-plans.html) both ideas of sending a crew to a deep-space destination or moving an asteroid to a Earth orbit had been abandoned in favor of what was really a sample return mission (although that term was never officially used). This would involve a robotic spacecraft which obtained a sample from an asteroid and returned it to an orbit near Earth, from which a crew would retrieve it.

[image]

By [June 2017](https://www.skyandtelescope.com/astronomy-news/nasa-closes-out-asteroid-redirect-mission/) the project was cancelled by the Trump administration.

To sum up, a sad history of descoping followed by cancellation.

1. Send crew to an asteroid (April 2010)
2. Bring an asteroid back (April 2013)
3. Bring a rock back (May 2015)
4. Cancellation (June 2017)

Comment: That is the exact opposite of how the features and expectations look for most projects that SE members work on.

Comment: @AaronHarun those projects probably start with real requirements instead of a posture of "here are the systems we are stuck with, is there *anything* we can do with them".

Comment: Sadly it's almost certainly going to happen to Artemis as well.